# Force union "∪" to typeset big

Tags: formatting

I'm asking about typing math in an inline text cell.  So in a text cell, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> puts the cursor in an inline cell.

Then <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>_</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> produces

[image: u12]

so evidently that subscript isn't "low enough" to influence the ∪ to be big.  If you do <kbd>q</kbd> instead of <kbd>2</kbd> in the subscript, it is "low enough" to make ∪ big:

[image: u1q]

but it seems what's to the left of ∪ takes precedence: type <kbd>a</kbd> at the left of the inline cell:

[image: au1q]

Small again.  That's not a huge issue, because I can place it in an adjacent inline cell.  The bigger issue is I can't figure out how to put ∪ at the center of an `UnderoverscriptBox`.  It always snaps to sub/superscripts and a small glyph instead of like in `DisplayForm`

[image: disp]

How should I be typesetting my math if not in inline text cells?  Is this similar to \scriptstyle \displaystyle shenanigans in $\TeX$?

Comment: One simple way that I often use (not with the union symbol though) is just to highlight the symbol in question, go to Menu/Format/Size and select the size of my wish.

Comment: In V13 you can use an inline TeX cell.

Answer (score 3):

You can control this with a style sheet. For example:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["InlineCell"], ScriptLevel->0, LimitsPositioningTokens->{}]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```